# Maintaining a large web service data set when the Application is destroyed

Tags: android, web-services, global-variables

In our application, we rely almost solely on data from our web service. On first launch, we start a `LoginActivity` where we handle logging in and retrieving this data before continuing onto the `MainActivity` where all of the UI that consumes the data begins.

We store the all of this data in a `static` data model, and it works great for what we need, however there are some instances when the application is killed off (due to memory constraints) while the `Activity` retains its state. So if I go and launch several other apps (to cause this to happen) then relaunch the app, it attempts to resume the `MainActivity` (which relies on the data from the service) and crashes due to fact that the application is no longer active and the data model no longer contains any data.

I've discovered that the `Application.onCreate()` method will be called in this case, so it seems like I'd want to handle returning to the login screen at that time, but it doesn't seem to be recommended practice to launch an activity from the application's context, not to mention that we'd already be in the process of resuming the activity.

What I would really like is for the application to *not* retain the activity state after the `Application` is no longer active (and all of the static data has been lost) and to just launch from the `LoginActivity` as expected.

This seems like a very common scenario; any suggestions on something simple that I may be overlooking, or any more info I can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.

Now I first check for static data in `onResume()` of `MainActivity`, while the static data is null I use `startActivityForResult` to open `LoginActivity` to prepare the static data, then continue when it returns `Activity.OK` in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I'm going to go this route; I'll just ensure not to call use any unchecked calls to the data model in my lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to have an app restarted to LoginActivity, first thing comes to mind is checking in every other `Activity.onCreate`:

```
if (yourStaticData == null) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

I'd suggest not doing that and making app behave correctly when the process is killed.

Comment: Surprisingly this doesn't work. We have multiple fragments within the activity, and when you call finish, even from onCreate(), it goes through and calls `onCreateView()` and other lifecycle methods for the Fragments (which rely on the data) before it actually finishes.

Comment: @kcoppock I'm glad it doesn't (easily). This is hacking on application architecture. You will have to wrap called `Fragments` code in this check too and do nothing if it is null. Ugly... And it should be. Resuming after process is killed should be no different from normal except for you have to load data into memory.

Comment: I agree to an extent, but I'd agree more if there were some sort of callback to let us know that the application was being destroyed. (e.g. an equivalent to `Application.onCreate()`)

Comment: That would be onCreate except for the first call to onCreate after booting the device or installing application ;)

Comment: That doesn't let us know the application is being destroyed, that lets us know it already *was* destroyed though.

Answer (score 0):

[clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) may be what You are looking for.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, and it's almost right, but I actually *do* want to retain the user's activity state until the data is gone.